# Deadlock graph in sql server profiler

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, sql-server-profiler

I am new to the concept of analyzing deadlock graph in profiler.I want to know that if I start my trace in sql server profiler and in that time no deadock occurs, willl be there any deadlock graph?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the trace for a longer period of time.  Note that profiler traces impact server peformance much more than server-side traces, so setup a server-side trace if possible, and write the output to table.

When you add the deadlock graph to a trace, you will get options to save the deadlock graphs to seperate .xdl files.  I recommend you do this, because you will need to open the file to see the deadlock graph... it is not shown in Profiler or by querying the trace table in SSMS.

Answer (score 2):

A deadlock graph will only appear in profiler if it is executing a trace which includes the "Deadlock Graph" event and a deadlock occurs whilst the trace is running.

If no deadlock occurs whilst the trace is running, no deadlock graph will appear.